# designing for 45+ years old users

Tags: website-design, usability, older-users

What are the things I need to consider when I design for the users that are 45-70 old?

I know a little about vision, hearing and dexterity problems, but what are other problems that some of you faced?

The scenario is: a travel website that allows users to view the destinations that we provide, sign up for newsletters and general information about travel

Comment: Be very careful, Igor. I'm getting 45 years old in april...

Comment: 45-70 will include people with very different needs. How did you identify that particular age range? It seems a little arbitrary.

Comment: @Matt Obee these people travel with us.

Comment: @Benny Skogberg my grand dad is 70 and he is using Internet and Skype without any problems. I noticed that he would miss on some icons(skype redesign, small chat icon when in video mode) I just want to make sure that the redesign wouldn't end up confusing the users more than helping them out.

Comment: @IgorG No worries mate :-)

Comment: I'm with Ben! Rocking my 44th year :) I think you are about 20 years off on the beginning of dexterity problems. Just make it easy to use for anyone.

Comment: @Itumac sorry guys wasn't trying to put you in "dexterity problem" group...

Comment: It ok sonny :) LOL. Its a funky age. It's like in gaming when your invincibility power-up fades and you are running around the same... but a little more vulnerable.

Comment: And it takes more training to do 10 km below 50 minutes. 25 years it took a month to go under 40 minutes, now it takes more than a year to reach 50 ;-)

Comment: @BennySkogberg: Quit complaining already young Benny! :-)) Had you waited till you were over your current age to start running like I did (started at 45), you'd never get below 50...

Comment: @MarjanVenema It get's worse? Damn! :-)

Comment: @BennySkogberg: yeah, real bummer! And injuries take twice as long to heal as well... About the only things I dislike about my age.

Comment: Ha ha. I'm 45 this year. My contrast vision is going and I've just bought my first pair of reading glasses at the chemist. Bigger type for us oldies please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only generalization I'd make about that age group is that often their eyesight declines, making the readability basics important:

- use default browser font size (i.e. don't set the font size for main
  text)
- use readable font (usually san serif font)
- [ensure adequate contrast](http://www.accesskeys.org/tools/color-contrast.html)
- layout for readability (attention to line length and leading)
- design page to be zoomed without breaking the layout

These ease reading for everyone, but are more important for the sight declined. They're the obvious guidelines, not a complete list. One place for more info is the [W3 Web Accessibility Initiative](http://www.w3.org/WAI/).

Comment: +1 for adequate contrast.  I'm 52 and have worn glasses all my life; things like the monochromatic VS2012 interface make it difficult for me to see all the little bits of available information on-screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of particular design considerations for those aged 45+, aside from the normal usability issues that affect all of us. I am aware of lots of guidelines when designing for older people aged 65+, most of which are common sense. There was, for example, a project within W3C in conjunction with the European Commission ([WAI-AGE](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WAI-AGE/)) looking at inclusive design for older people. One of the things they looked at was making websites more accessible and usable [**by applying WCAG guidelines**](http://www.w3.org/WAI/older-users/developing.html).

One thing to bear in mind is that there is actually a lot of diversity in older age groups when it comes to confidence with technology. Some older people will have been using computers and browsing the web quite happily for many years. Some will have attended classes and received training more recently than younger people!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly 45 to 70 is a massive span of target audience. They may be web savvy or not so inclined towards online buying (in specific context to India).

Characteristics of a 45 something traveler is:  budget is not a issue, planed trip for them is essential.
Content guidelines: site has to be Content rich;  location images have to be impressive, feedback of travelers and their recommendations. 
Interaction guidelines: commitment and actionable decisions should be aimed,page save/ plan save features, share your travel plan,compare features are suggested.

Characteristics of a 60 to 70 age group:memory can be depleating along with sight, health considerations, food considerations, travel companion considerations. 
Content guidelines: Details of stay, parking, availability of lift, room and locations climatic conditions, walking distances and terrain etc.
Interaction guidelines:popular guidelines should be followed(least mental load),reminders and notifications, sharing and saving features, offline downloads are desirable considerations.

Good luck

Comment: Interesting claims. Do you have sources?

Comment: I am a design faculty and researcher, i have mentored several research projects that have seniors age group. the response is in line with the study of their challenges and lifestyle.

Comment: Ok. I was hoping to read more about your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few more facets to consider validating that your subset of older users isn't harmed by your UI or UX.

- **Cultural references.** You edit out language and symbols that don't translate cleanly by language or region. Do the same generationally. Check that you're not using verbal or visual metaphors grounded in the last five minutes.
- **Cognitive burden.** Remember "Don't Make Me Think" as a design goal? More so. Be more ruthless in cutting back on distractions, breadth of choices.
- **Speed and timing.** Measure how long it takes for text to be read, for navigation choices to be parsed, for gestures to happen. Look hard at timeouts and the distance between between groups of items to be touched/seen.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the market, but our usability studies in the lab consistently show issues that Western 45+ y.o. users have with iOS standards, either adopted for web or used natively. And some of the Material Design standards. For example, they don't understand that a) or b) is a button. 
[image]

Based on this, I would steer clear of the latest standards and use a bit of skeumorphism for controls to ensure my userbase understands all.